# Who is attending Eurographics 2016?

Tags: discussion

I meant to post this way earlier but somehow forgot about it. Are any users of the community this week's Eurographics in Lisbon, Portugal? This might be a nice opportunity to promote the community a bit, and maybe also for members of the community to meet up if they want.

Let me know in the answers if anyone's around and we can set up a chatroom (or use [The Cornell Box](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26589/the-cornell-box)) to work out any details if people want to meet up.